# How to mount an external drive's ext4 partition on android and make it rw-available to all the apps

Tags: android, linux

I have written the following shell script:

```
alias mount='/system/xbin/busybox mount'
set -e
set -x

MNT=sda1

function mkdir_ext() {
  if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
    mkdir -p $1
  fi
  chown $2 $1
  chmod $3 $1
}

mkdir_ext /storage/emulated/$MNT root:media_rw 777
mount -t ext4 /dev/block/$MNT /storage/emulated/$MNT

mkdir_ext /data/media/$MNT root:media_rw 777
sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 /storage/emulated/$MNT /data/media/$MNT
```

After executing the commands above, mount reports:

```
root@NEO-X8:/sdcard # mount|grep sda
/dev/block/sda1 /storage/emulated/sda1 ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/fuse /data/media/sda1 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
```

I am working via ssh, remotely, using [rooted ssh/sftp daemon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=web.oss.sshsftpDaemon), and while logged in as root, I can list the files in `/storage/emulated/sda1`.

From what I understand, android is case-insensitive in regards to filesystems by design, so the filesystem has to be fused.

The problem is, I see just an empty directory in `/data/media/sda1`. Even stranger is that, if I navigate to `/storage/emulated/sda1` from the device as root with [bash shell X](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitcubate.android.bash.installer), I also see an empty directory.

I have tried different other apps and I've tried to also use `sdcard_rw` instead of `media_rw` (with the uid / gid 1015 instead of 1023), nothing works.

How to get ext4 to work for all apps on a rooted Minix NEO X8-H? Using anything but ext4 is not an option, the 4TB drive already contains important data. As a side note, `sda1` is just a small 1GB partition.

Comment: Neither Android nor ext4 is case insensitive, though some other filesystems and emulation schemes it uses for things like "external storage" may be so.   You may be running into the fact that each process ancestry on Android has a unique set of mounts - so what you do in a setuid process descending from one app won't necessary be reflected in another or in adb.

Comment: Are you saying that it's not possible to access an external USB drive from all apps?

Comment: Not necessarily, but more that you efforts so far may not have accomplished mounting it for everyone.  What does "mount" give as output in shells where it is not accessible?

Comment: Those mount points do not appear. So do you have an idea about a solution?

Comment: No, but at least we know what the problem is.  At this point it might be worth doing some reading on how the per-process mounts feature in Linux works, as that is what Android is leveraging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that your device is rooted from what you have done so far so will not go into that. Though I cannot be certain this is your issue I shall explain how I solved a similar problem.

Resent versions of android with the intent on improving device security are now using the (somewhat half arsed) feature of making mounts performed by most processes not visible to other processes. Working around this is frustratingly device specific, however it appears the Minix NEO X8-H is using a "vanilla" style source build of android. Therefore you have a good chance of using [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=en) in order to mount the USB stick, it should enable the global mounting of USB devices running any file-system supported by your ROM (which should include ext4 given you have already mounted it before).

I have not tested this personally on your device so cannot guarantee it will work but have had success with a number of other android devices so this is certainly worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I use `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdf2` format SDcard and insert into samsung s4 anrdoid phone.

```
adb shell 
su
mount /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /root
```

I cant't mount this SDcard, I have googled it but no solution.

The last, I found this can succeed :)))

```
mk2fs -t ext4 /dev/sdf2
and ...
```